# A question about regularity of parameterizations of a surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Can someone give an example of two permetrazations (1-1) of a surface that satisfy: At a same point (on the surface) one permetrazation is regular but the other is not regular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the $xy$-plane $S$. Then we can give a 1-1 parametrization $\overline{x}:\mathbb{R}^2\to S$ given by
 $$\overline{x}(u,v)=(u,v,0),$$
which is regular (which you can check yourself). 
Now, consider another parametrization $\overline{y}:\mathbb{R}^2\to S$ given by
 $$\overline{y}(u,v)=(u^3,v^3,0),$$
Then it is still 1-1 parametrization of $S$, but it is not regular, since the differential of $\overline{y}$ at $(u,v)=(0,0)$ is given by 
$$d\overline{y}_{(0,0)}=\left.\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    3u^2 & 0 \\
    0 & 3v^2 \\
    0 & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\right]\right|_{(u,v)=(0,0)}=\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\right]$$
which does not have full column rank.